# DateTime.Parse String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

Code has been simplified for ease of asking question, string is pulled from an array and has been verified to be exactly as provided below. The below code results in error:

**Message:  "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."**

```
string myDate = "20221215.08.14.01.37";
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(myDate);
```

I was expecting the string to be converted to DateTime, have tried working with other DateTime methods such as TryParse, and providing formatting, without success.

Comment: well, _i_ certainly don't know what datetime this is supposed to be. seems you have to use [ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-6.0) and provide a format definition

Comment: Totally expected. What formats did you try?

Comment: [Converts the string representation of a date and time to its DateTime equivalent by using the conventions of the current culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=net-7.0)

Comment: "_20221215.08.14.01.37_" What is that? A Federation stardate? A day on Cthulhu's abominable calendar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is unusual format so `Parse` cannot handle that. You have to use `DateTime.ParseExact`:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(myDate, "yyyyMMdd.HH.mm.ss.ff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

See more info about format specifiers [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

Comment: This works on provided string, thank you. It still does not work in my code though, I got the value from debugger and pasted it here. Will continue to troubleshoot, marked as correct answer as it does work with a declared variable as presented here.